# Starting a new job knowing you will quit after few months

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, new-job, ethics, hiring

Following graduation, I was looking for my first ever real job few months ago. I had two great interviews with my dream company (A) and this other company on my radar (B).

First offer came from company (B). Even though it wasn't my top company, I accepted it not knowing if I will get an offer from company A. I tried to stall for some time, but B wanted an answer summarily.

After few weeks, I was offered a position from company A. At this time, I was ready to quit from company B and head over to A because it had only been few weeks, and I was still on my probationary period. However, Company A decided to postpone my start date to next quarter, which means approximately 5 months later.

I nonetheless accepted because I really want to work at this company for a long, long time. So, now I am in this ethical crisis. My probation period at company B is about to end, and I am about to become a full time. I feel really bad/guilty about continuing working knowing I will be quitting in 5 months. I would quit right now, but my loans and expenses have started to accrete, so I need an immediate source of income.

If I go to my boss (who's a very nice person) explaining the situation, I know he/she will definitely let me go (at will employment) because I am essentially wasting his/her time so its not in their best interest to keep me. What is your opinion on this matter? Have you ever encountered this situation in the past? If so, how did you go about it?

Comment: Title indicates you have not yet joined the new company which you are considering leaving but from your post it sounds like you have joined and already finishing probation there.

Comment: There isnt any ethical crisis. You will work 6 months and then move. As long you perfom the work you was hired for. You are OK. They dont expect you work for them all your life.

Answer (score 10):

Well, seems that you already decided to go for your dream company, and that is not bad actually (it is your life, your career).

The "good" thing I see here is that:

1. **You are on probation period, and this is one of the reasons why probation periods exist**, to see if both parts are a good fit to each other, and to compensate for any "early" leaving.
2. By the time you should quit **you will have worked there for 6 months**, which is the minimum time some folks consider for a "decent" work experience (in other words, you are not affecting them as much as if you left earlier, and may also consider including this experience on your resume).

So, what I suggest is that you **wait as much as you can before discussing this with your boss**, so you don't risk losing your job months before you start the other one. Just remember to **respect the Notice Period stated in your contract**, and present such within the specified time to avoid possible problems.

Answer (score 2):

Serve your appropriate notice period at B and join A. Keep your "unemployed" time in between as minimum as you can afford. There is nothing more to it. You may or may not burn bridges with B but that is something you will have to take chances with.

There are several related questions like [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/107385/how-to-tell-a-superior-i-wont-be-able-to-complete-a-task-because-i-am-going-to)  on how to accept/decline responsibilities when you know you are leaving soon. You can get more insights from there on professionally maintaining your stay while you are at B.

Comment: I think you miss a word after `join A with as ... ` i guess, short or small ?

Comment: My intent was to say Join A with as less time as between..I can see how it can be confusing. Hence edited for clarity